# WCF webHttpBinding find request parameters which where not mapped

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I've created an http service which uses WCF with webHttpBindings to access the data through HTTP. Everything is working as it should be, but now I got the question to give an error when a parameter was passed that was not used for processing the request. Like when the case of a parameter is wrong, or if was misspelled, it doesn't get mapped to the correct variable.

If for example I have a data model like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Contact{
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="age")]
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

If I have a method using this Contact, the user can just pass it in the request body like so:

```
{"name":"InsertName","age":23}
```

But, if the names of the properties in the request don't exactly match the DataMembers in the model, their value gets lost.

```
{"Nam":"InsertName","age":23}
```

Is there a way to find out that a `Nam` parameter was added to the HTTP request body but that it was not mapped to the parameters of  my WCF method?